# HTML/JS - Cannot get textbox 3 to update after text entered into textbox 1+2?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to take the numbers entered into `tbQtyFailed` and `tbQtyTested`,calculate the % rate, and then show the % in `tbFailurePercent`. I thought I could make a JS function and then assign the `tbFailurePercents` value with the results but cannot get it to work and am unsure why. I have attached the code. Thanks!

```
<td>Qty Tested:</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="tbQtyTested">
</td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PercentageMath() {
        var qtyTested = document.getElementById("tbQtyTested");
        var qtyFailed = document.getElementById("tbQtyFailed");
        var failurePercent = parseFloat(qtyTested.value) / parseFloat(qtyFailed.value);

        var display = document.getElementById("tbFailurePercent");
        display.value = failurePercent;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("tbFailurePercent").value = "NAN";
    }
    };
</script>
<tr>
    <td>Bag Number of Previous Test Period:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="tbPreviousPeriod">
    </td>
    <td>Result(s):</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="tbResults" value="" onchange="PercentageMath()">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bag Numbers within Failure Scope:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="tbBagsWithinScope">
    </td>
    <td>Failure % (Failed/Tested):</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="tbFailurePercent" disabled>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You have an `else` but no if

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE], preferably in a Plunker/Fiddle. You have an `else` without an `if`, and I don't see the `tbQuantityFailed` element.

Comment: @ artm - The else was a missed left over of previous failings. @Igor Raush - I missed the tbQuantityFailed in my copying of the code. Thank you guys anyway, sorry for the crap paste job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was missing a field for the qty failed and the result field didn't make any sense. I have no idea what the bag fields are for either.

```js
function perc() {
  var qtyT = document.getElementById("qtyT").value;
  var qtyF = document.getElementById("qtyF").value;
  var fRes = document.getElementById("failPerc");
  var pRes = document.getElementById("passPerc");
  var failPerc = parseFloat(qtyF) / parseFloat(qtyT);
  //console.log('fail%: ' + failPerc);
  var passPerc = parseFloat(1 - failPerc);
  //console.log('pass%: ' + passPerc);
  fRes.value = (failPerc * 100) + "%";
  pRes.value = (passPerc * 100) + "%";
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Qty Tested:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="qtyT">
      </td>
      <td>Qty Failed:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="qtyF" oninput="perc();">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Bag#PrevTest:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="bagPrev">
      </td>
      <td>Passed:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="passPerc" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bag#FailScope:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="bagFail">
      </td>
      <td>Failed:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="failPerc" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: tbQtyFailed was missed in the pasting and I should have removed the bag fields in my code snippet, as they were not pertinent. I know pretty much nothing about HTML but got stuck with this project at work, so thank you. May I ask why fRes and pRes are necessary? Why doesn't _document.getElementById("failPerc").value = partseInt(qtyF)/parseInt(qtyT)_ work? What is the need for the temporary variables? Is it because you have to "load" the items into the function otherwise it cannot access them?

Comment: The reason why there's some flip-flopping of variables is because it rarely works out for me if I attempt to condense too many steps in an expression. I'm sure there's a more streamlined way to cut down some steps, but in the long run, I usually end up needing to hook into those extra steps to branch off into another function. I think the failPerc.value = qtyF/qtyT wasn't used is because usually in an expression, I find a solid variable on the left of the `=` and an expression on the right side of `=` rarely fails.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean...I didn't use `paresInt` because integers are whole numbers, you can't get anything right of a decimal (e.g. 0.01). With `parseFloat` you can. Btw, if you want to get a smaller result, use `.toFixed()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: Thank you again for the help! Oh that was a typo on the parseInt, I do know the difference for that at least lol.